# How do I translate a PHP cURL request to python

Tags: python, php, curl, whmcs

I'm coding a tool to get Whois info, and I need to use the WHMCS API for it.

This is the code they provide:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example.com/includes/api.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    http_build_query(
        array(
            'action' => 'DomainGetWhoisInfo',
            // See https://developers.whmcs.com/api/authentication
            'username' => 'IDENTIFIER_OR_ADMIN_USERNAME',
            'password' => 'SECRET_OR_HASHED_PASSWORD',
            'domainid' => '1',
            'responsetype' => 'json',
        )
    )
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I want to use this request without PHP, and inside Python. What library should I use and how do I set the variables in the payload?(php or python-style?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What library should I use*

[`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) is popular `python` module for working with HTTP(S) requests, note however that it is external module and needs to be installed as follows

```
pip install requests
```

It is not hard to do, but if you are not allowed to install external module you can not use it. In such situation you might use [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) built-in module.

*how do I set the variables in the payload?*

Just translate your `array` to `python`'s `dict` and use it as `data` argument, [requests Quickstart](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) provide following example

```
r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data={'key': 'value'})
```

`{'key': 'value'}` is `python`'s equivalent to `PHP7`'s
`array('key' => 'value')` and `{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}` would be `array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2')` and so on